# How to display javascript variable values in a table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently in the process of creating a table that displays the variable values. I'm having trouble with implementing the values into my table. I have attached the code that I have so far. When I run this code I get "undefined" instead of the values. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script>
    var outputHTML = "";
    var countries = {
        "US": "Washington DC",
        "UK": "London",
        "Germany" : "Berlin",
        "Estonia": "Tallinn",
        "Morocco": "Rabat",
        "Niger": "Niamey" 
    };

    outputHTML += "<table border='2px' width='400'>";
    for (var i =1; i <=6; i++) {
        outputHTML += "<tr>";
        for (var j =1; j <=2; j++) {
                outputHTML += "<td>" + countries[i] + "</td>";
        }
        outputHTML +="</tr>";
    }
    outputHTML += "</table>";

    
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = outputHTML;
</script>
```

Comment: Here ```countries``` is object, So you cannot use ```contries[i]``` which will return undefined. Instead you need to convert the object to array and then assign the value.

Comment: `i` and `j` should be 0 not 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having countries as an object like you have shown is unusual and it might not be what you want.

Its more common to have array of objects like this

```
var countries = [
    {  
        country: 'US',
        city:  'Washington DC'
    },
    {  
        country: 'UK',
        city:  'London'
    },
    // etc
];
```

and then you would access them like this
note that the first element of an array is 0

```
for (let i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
        outputHTML += '<tr><td>' + countries[i].country + '</td>'
                   + <td>' + countries[i].city + '</td></tr>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Object.keys(countries).forEach( key => // for loop here )` instead of for loop, and key will be prop name.

i.e. in the forEach loop `countries[key]` will get you the value, while `key` will get you the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Object.entries(countries)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries) to turn the object into a two dimensional array.

```js
var outputHTML = "";
var countries = {
    "US": "Washington DC",
    "UK": "London",
    "Germany" : "Berlin",
    "Estonia": "Tallinn",
    "Morocco": "Rabat",
    "Niger": "Niamey" 
};

outputHTML += "<table border='2px' width='400'>";

//REM: Returns the key/value of the object as array[[key, value]]
let tValues = Object.entries(countries);

//REM: Note - use .length instead of static 6 or foreach
//for (var i =1; i <=6; i++) {
tValues.forEach((item) => {
    outputHTML += "<tr>";
    
    //REM: We know item has two entries, so we can omit this loop.
    //for(var j =0; j <=1; j++) {
    //        outputHTML += "<td>" + item[j] + "</td>";
    //}
    
    outputHTML += "<td>" + item[0] + "</td>";
    outputHTML += "<td>" + item[1] + "</td>"; 
    outputHTML +="</tr>";
})
outputHTML += "</table>";

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = outputHTML;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```